# How to declare function with argument that is a closure in C++11 in a Cuda device function?

Tags: c++, c++11, cuda, closures, function-templates

I'm working on Cuda with C++11 (I don't think Cuda supports later C++ versions yet).  I've a closure object that is passed to the function `Process()` which calls the closure for each iteration.

I understand that `std::` functionality is generally not available in Cuda.  For example, when I try to use `std::function< float(uint32_t) >`, I get this error:

> error: calling a **host** function("std::function ::function< ::, void, void> ") from a **global** function("_NV_ANON_NAMESPACE::LargeKernel") is not allowed

What can I replace `lookupFunc` with so that this compiles without `std::function` being available?  I was able to work around this by creating a function template to deduce the type of the lambda function.

This code works and shows the work around I've employed:

```
//using lookupFunc = std::function< float(uint32_t) >;

template< typename Lambda > // Work around with function template
__device__
void Process(float       * const outData,
             const  int32_t      locationX,
             const Lambda /* lookupFunc */ lambda)
{
    float answer = 0.f;

    for( int32_t offset = -1 ; ++offset < 1024 ; )
    {
        const float value = lambda( offset );

        answer += value;
    }

    outData[ locationX ] = answer;
}

__global__
void LargeKernel(const float * const inData,
                 float       * const outData)
{
    constexpr uint32_t cellStride = 1;
    const     int32_t  locationX  = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    const auto lambda
        = [locationX, inData, cellStride](const int32_t offset)
          {
              return inData[ locationX + offset + cellStride ];
          };

    Process( outData, locationX, lambda );
}
```

I also tried:

```
using lookupFunc = float(* const)(uint32_t);
```

But that gives error:

> error: no suitable conversion function from "const lambda ->float" to "float (*)(uint32_t)" exists

How can I declare the type of the third argument to `Process()` without using a template?

Comment: The [Cuda Programming Guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#c-cplusplus-language-support) tells us about C++14 support from version 9.0 on. And there is `nvstd::function`, see e.g. [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#polymorphic-function-wrappers).

Comment: @Shadow That resolves the question, can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CUDA equivalent to `std::function` is `nvstd::function`.
As of CUDA 8.0 `nvstd::function` can be used in host and device code - but "instances cannot be passed from host code to device code (and vice versa) at run time".
Its use is explained in the [CUDA programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#polymorphic-function-wrappers).

Answer (score 0):

Is necessary to use a lambda?

Otherwise, you can simulate it declaring a `struct`

```
struct noLambda
 {
   std::int32_t const   locationX;
   float const * const  inData;
   std::uint32_t const  cellStride;

   noLambda (std::int32_t l0, float const * const i0, std::uint32_t c0)
      : locationX{l0}, inData{i0}, cellStride{c0}
    { }

   float operator() (std::int32_t const offset) const
    { return inData[ locationX + offset + cellStride ]; }
 };
```

So the signature of process become

```
void Process(float       * const outData,
             const  int32_t      locationX,
             const noLambda lambda)
```

and is callable as follows

```
Process( outData, locationX, noLambda{locationX, inData, cellStride} );
```

(caution: code not tested)

Comment: Yes, I need to use lambda, the above example is a simplified one to demonstrate the issue.